# A greatest common divisor problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that given  positive integers $p$ and $q$, if $p x + q y =1$ for integers $x$ and $y$ with $x>0$ then 
\begin{align*}
p&=\gcd\left( \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4 m n}}{2},  n \right)\\
q&=\gcd\left( \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4 m n}}{2},  n \right)
\end{align*}
where $n=pq$ and $m=x y$.

So far I have:

First consider $p x + q m /x=1$. Solving for $x$
$$
 x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4 m n}}{2p}
$$
Since $x>0$, the solution is
$$
 x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1-4 m n}}{2p}
$$
Therefor $p \mid \frac{1 + \sqrt{1-4 m n}}{2}$. Since $p \mid n$,
we conclude $p=s\gcd(\frac{1 + \sqrt{1-4 m n}}{2},n)$ for some integers $s$.
Noting that $y<0$ and $p m/y + q y=1$, reasoning in a similar fashion, we conclude
$q=t \gcd\left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{1-4 m n}}{2},  n \right)$ for some integer $t$.

How can I show $s$ and $t$ are equal to 1?

Comment: When I take $1=5\times 3 - 7\times 2$, then $1-4mn=211$. But 211 is not a perfect square then how can you talk of gcd of the quantities you mention?

Comment: You are wrong in the step introducing $s$.

When we have $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$ in general, we could conclude $as=gcd(b,c)$ for some $s$ but not $a=sgcd(b,c)$ for some $s$.

As in your case, the $s$ should be in the $p$ side of the equation.

Comment: You are right. I'd have edited, but there is already an answer that clarifies that.

Comment: @PVanchinathan $1-4mn=841$. You dropped multiplication by $4$.

Comment: @mhp: thanks for the clarification, definitely I've blundered. As we know that quantity is a perfect square why cant we write the expressions in your question avoiding $m,n$ and the square root as: $p=\gcd(1-qy,pq)$, and $q=\gcd(qy, pq)$

Comment: The point is to write an expression in terms of the product of $p$ and $q$, avoiding free occurrences of $p$ or $q$. There are many applications for this, not least of which is factoring $n$, where $p$ and $q$ are unknown, but $n=pq$ is known. What I gave above is not a factorization method either since $m=xy$ is unknown.

Comment: By the way, $px +qy=1$ is the Bezout identity when $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think that what you have shown is :

$$gcd(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4mn}}{2},n)=ps\text{ and } gcd(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4mn}}{2},n)=qt $$

Secondly, I assume here that $\sqrt{1-4mn}$ is an integer (it does not seem obvious why it is so).

We want to show that $s$ is $1$. then $s$ divides $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4mn}}{2}$, and $s$ divides $\frac{n}{p}=q$. So that $s$ must be a  divisor of $q$.

Now because of what you have shown $s$ divides $q$ which divides $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4mn}}{2}$. Now $s$ divides both $\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4mn}}{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4mn}}{2}$ so it divides their sum which is one. So $s=1$.

Of course, the same thing applies to $t$ and you are good.

Comment: There are several ways to see that the square root is an integer. The easiest is by noting that LHS, $x$, is an integer. Another way is to write $\sqrt{1-4mn}=\sqrt{1-4 p x q y}=\sqrt{1-4 qy (1-qy)}=\sqrt{(1 - qy)^2}$.

Comment: @mhp, thank you I definitely did not see that point...

Comment: Too late to correct the algebraic error: the last equality in my previous comment should read $\sqrt{(1-2 q y)^2}$.